# A question on Paul Garrett's exposition on the Gelfand-Kazhdan Criterion

Tags: proof-explanation, representation-theory

Here is Paul Garrett's exposition on the [Gelfand-Kazhdan Criterion](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/gelfand_kazhdan.pdf).

In page 4 of the exposition, he showed the following lemma.

> Lemma: Let $B, t, S$ be as above and for $\alpha, \beta$ in $C_c^\infty(G)$, we have
> $$B(\alpha \otimes \beta) = t( S(\beta \ast \alpha)).$$

In his proof, he state the following
$$B(\alpha \otimes \beta) = T\alpha (S \beta) = \int_G \alpha(x) t(x \cdot S \beta) \, dx =\int_G \alpha(x) t( S (R_x^{-1} \cdot \beta)) \, dx.$$
The first equality follows directly from definition, however I am unable to verify the second equality. Instead I obtain the following identity
$$x\cdot S\beta = S(R_x \cdot \beta)$$ for $x \in G$ and hence
$$\int_G \alpha(x) t(x \cdot S \beta) \, dx = \int_G \alpha(x) t( S(R_x \cdot \beta)) \, dx.$$

Here is my proof. Given $v \in (\pi, V)$ and $x \in G$, we have
\begin{align*}
(x \cdot S\beta)(v) &= (S\beta)(x^{-1} v)\\
& = \int_G \beta(y) s(yx^{-1}\cdot v) \, dy\\
&=\int_G \beta(yx) s(y \cdot v) \, dy\\
&=\int_G (R_x \beta)(y) s(y \cdot v) \, dy \\
&=[S(R_x \beta)](v).
\end{align*}
where $\beta \in C_c^\infty(G)$ and $S \beta \in \check \pi$ and since $v \in V$ is arbitrary we have $x\cdot S\beta = S(R_x \cdot \beta)$ which is contrary to Paul's proof.

Could anyone verify if there is any gap in my work?